# Python / Add previous element from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to Python and trying to do something but cannot figure out how...

```
x = 20
list = [5, 3, 7]
```

I want to create a loop that add the previous element from the list to x

Loop 1 : result = 20+0 = 20 (no previous element)

Loop 2 : result = 20+5 = 25

Loop 3 : result = 20+5+3 = 28

So at the end result should look like that :
result = [20, 25, 28]

Any idea how I could achieve this result ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is your `x`, `10` or `20`?

Comment: 20 (I edited the post)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> my_list = [5, 3, 7]
>>> [x + sum(my_list[:n]) for n in range(len(my_list))]
[10, 15, 18]
```

Note that naming a list `list` is a bad idea because it overwrites the builtin `list` function!

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
x = 20
my_list = [5, 3, 7]
result = [x]
for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
    x += my_list[i]
    result.append(x)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
x = 20
lst = [5, 3, 7]
lst = [x+sum([lst[i] for i in range(i)]) if i else x for i,n in enumerate(lst)]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[20, 25, 28]
```